# How to use Select-Xml cmdlet to parse XML from external source?

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, select-xml

I'm trying to use `Select-Xml` to parse XML from SQL server.
I have a sql query which gives me an XML string (`$Query`) and I want to sum up all "Users" values from this XML.

My script works perfectly if I use external file for "`-Path`".
But I don't know how to use put XML string into "`-Path`".

If I run  `Write-Host $path` i'm getting just a "System.Data.DataRow" message

If I run  `echo $path` i'm getting XML string.

```
$XPath = "//Users" # XML element
$total = 0 # Counter to sum up all Users elements

$Query = "SELECT [LicXML] FROM [SQLSERVER].[dbo].[Conf] WHERE Name='Lic'" # Query to get XML string
$path = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance 'SQLSERVER' -Database SQLDB # Request to MSSQL

Select-Xml -Path $path -XPath $Xpath | ForEach-Object { $total += [int] $_.node.InnerXML }; # Parsing
Write-Host "total:" $total # Users sum
```

I tried different ways but still have no idea. Could you help me please?

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1EGj.jpg)

**UPD.** I'm too dumb for this place.
Firstly, I must use `-Content` flag instead of `-Path`
But still dont' know how to put my XML string to the `-Content`

**UPD2.** I believe I can use `$path = $path | Out-String` to push the XML string in my variable. But now I have other problem - how to cut off the header of the query result? Because it's not a valid XML until the header is presented:

```
Select-Xml : Cannot convert value "
LicXML                                                                                                                                                    
-------                                                                                                                                                    
<License ProductID="ICE"><Data Version="1.0" AuthenticationKeyID="PCApps">...
" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument"
```

Comment: Does the database contain a file path, or the raw xml?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's the raw xml

Comment: Then you want to pass it to either `-InputObject` or pipe it: `$path.BigStr |Select-Xml ...`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Actually I'm stuck with removing a header :( could you help with that?

Comment: Assuming `Invoke-SqlCmd` returns a datarow with a `LicXML` column, you should be able to get the raw string value by referencing `$path["LicXML"]` (I got confused by the "BigStr1" column header in the error message, did you mannualy change it?)

Comment: Conversely, if the column name is indeed `BigStr1`: `$path["BigStr1"] |Select-Xml ...`

Answer (score 0):

Finally:

```
$XPath = "//Users" #XML Value to find
$total = 0 #Counter to sum up Users
$Query = "SELECT [LicXML] FROM [SQLSERVER].[dbo].[Conf] WHERE Name='Lic'" #Query to gather raw XML string
$path = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance SQLSERVER #Sending a query
$path["LicXML"] | Select-Xml -XPath $Xpath | ForEach-Object { $total += [int] $_.node.InnerXML }; #Black magic, XML parsing and counting a sum
```